# Parse server - Parse.User.become(sessionToken) - Invalid Session

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

Trying something that should be simple, creating a new User account from an Admin dashboard using Parse server on Back4app.

Every time I try the new user is created but I am unable to switch back to the original user...

```
var sessionToken = Parse.User.current().getSessionToken();

                        Parse.User.signUp(email, email).then(function(newUser) {
                            Parse.User.logOut();
                            Parse.User.become(sessionToken);
                        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

logOut and become are asynchronous functions, if I'm not mistaken. So you're trying to become another user when you haven't logged out of the original user, which I don't think works.

Answer (score 0):

All of these parse user functions you are using returns a promise, I suspect there is some asynchronous magic going on - try chaining them together like this and see if that fixes the issue.

```
Parse.User.signUp(email, email)
.then(function(newUser) 
{ return Parse.User.logOut()}
.then(function() { return Parse.User.become(sessionToken)}
```

For reference:

http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_logOut

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it does not seem to help, I suppose I need to put the code in Cloud code and call a function.